# incorporating cURL output string in BASH variables

Tags: bash, curl

I would like to make the process of getting data automatic (I want to have an app that sends/receives data from a car). I'm able to manually do this by copying/pasting results from cURL queries, but I want to put this into a BASH shell script and I don't know how to transfer the results from one cURL command to the next. Here's an example:

```
result="$(curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"\
        -F "grant_type=password" -F "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" -F "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" -F "email=$EMAIL" -F "password=$PASSWORD"\
        "https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/oauth/token")"
```

The output from this is:

```
result:'{"access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3888000,"refresh_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","created_at":1592850440}'
```

where XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a hidden entry. I'm a novice programmer and am unable to take part of the result (e.g. "access_token") and put it in the next cURL:

```
curl --include --header "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}" "https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles"
```

Is there an easy way to do this with BASH or is it better to use JavaScript or Python? (I'm not very good at any). Other commands return even more complicated strings with 10's of fields. I will want to manipulate these variables (some of which are real numbers, not strings) in the BASH shell. I've tried awk but don't see an easy way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `jq` to process the JSON data, or better yet use Python Requests which makes it very simple for novices to get along. With plain shell and curl you have to do too much manually.

Answer (score 0):

A program like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) will allow you to parse the json output and access specific attributes from within it.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- `${result}` will always be a single-line string of characters
- OP knows the expected format for a given `curl` result
- the colon (`:`) and comma (`,`) only show up as a field delimiters

Our sample data:

```
$ result='{"access_token":"OUR_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3888000,"refresh_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","created_at":1592850440}'
$ echo "${result}"
{"access_token":"OUR_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3888000,"refresh_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","created_at":1592850440}
```

A simple `awk` solution for a `curl` result where we want the `access_token` value:

```
$ awk -F[:,] '               # define input field separators as colon or comma
{ print $2 }                 # desired token is in field 2
' <<< "${result}"            # feed ${result} as a here-string
"OUR_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

To capture this in a variable for later use:

```
$ access_token=$(awk -F[:,] '{ print $2}' <<< "${result}")
$ echo ".${access_token}."   # periods added as visual delimiters for this example
."OUR_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN".
```

This could then be fed to the next `curl` call like such:

```
$ curl --include --header "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" ...
```

If we preface our call with `set -xv` we should see:

```
$ set -xv                        # turn on debugging
$ curl --include --header "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" ...
++ curl --include --header 'Authorization: Bearer "OUR_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN"' ...
```

And if you need to remove the double quotes one option could be:

```
$ curl --include --header "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token//\"/}" ...
$ ++ curl --include --header 'Authorization: Bearer OUR_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN' ...
$ set +xv                        # turn off debugging
```

---

If the assumptions aren't always valid (eg, delimiters also show up in the data; result has embedded linefeeds; etc) then you can opt for a more complex `awk` solution or consider the other answers/suggestions of using a tool (eg, `jq`) designed for parsing the results from `curl`.